# Time of connection to DB using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

When I test the run time like this,the time on my machine is `735`

```
 public class TestDBCP {

    static
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        for(int i =0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbcdemo","root","Sph815@cs");
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - l);
    }

     }
```

But when I test it using the following its run time becomes longer, i don't understand why more job fewer time?

```
public class TestDBCP {

static
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        for(int i =0; i < 100; i++)
        {
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbcdemo","root","Sph815@cs");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - l);
    }

}
```

Comment: Huh? More job fewer time?

Comment: Have you checked your GC? Would it be that since you don't code the connections in your second example they hang on to much more objects thus putting more strain on the GC?

Comment: sorry the first one with more job fewer time

Comment: I don't know what's GC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that execute an extra statement (the one that close the connection) will implies that the program will take more time because the close() statement execution adds extra CPU usage.

If you doesn't execute it, you save this CPU time, however the database has to deal with more [open connections simultaneously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_connection#Pooling), which can degrade his performance. Therefore, the getConnection() statement will takes longer to execute as the number of open connections increases.

Probably this is the reason your second version execute slower than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the connection immediately in the second one. Opening and closing one connection 100 times won't take nearly as long as opening 100 connections at once.

Comment: they're all open at the same time

Comment: yeah i know but at the same time? I don't understand

Comment: @user3451524 you ask for con 1 and do not close it, then you ask for con 2, so con 1 and 2 are open at the same time, the DB thinks you are doing two different things / there are tow clients